# Login jquery, object json, ajax, variable session in web service c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I have a login in my web service with a variable of session, I got it with code behind, but now I need to do it again with jQuery. This is my web method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public Credencial SetSession(Credencial parametro)
    {
        RNLogin _login = new RNLogin();
        Credencial res = new Credencial();
        res.Nick = parametro.Nick;
        res.Password = parametro.Password;
        res.Identificador = _login.Login(res);
        if(res.Identificador > 0)
        {
           HttpContext.Current.Session["Identificador"] = res.Identificador;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

And here my html code with ajax, but at the moment to put my object json in data, it give me an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnPrueba').click(function () {
                var nombre = $('#txtNombre').val();
                var paterno = $('#txtPaterno').val();

                MiFuncionObj(nombre, paterno);

            });
        });

        function MiFuncionObj(nick, password) {
           // alert("nick = " + nick + ",pass =" + password)
            //var actiondata = "{'nombre': '" + nombre + "','Paterno':'" + paterno + "'}";
            var objJson = {
                "Nick": nick, "Password": password
            }

            var actiondata = JSON.stringify(objJson);

            $.ajax({
             url: "wsSesion.asmx/SetSession",
            // data: actiondata,
            data: "{'parametro':" + '<%= actiondata %>' + "}", //objeto json con el nombre 
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
                //  success: function (msg) { alert(msg.d); },
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d.Identificador > 0) {
                    alert("TU Nick: " + msg.d.Nick + ", TU Identificador:  " + msg.d.Identificador);
                   window.location.href = "Acceso.aspx";
                }
                else {
                    alert("Usuarios y/o password incorectos");
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("ERROR" + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
            }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   Nombre: <input type="text" id="txtNombre"/><br />
   Paterno: <input type="text" id="txtPaterno"/><br />

    <input type="button" id="btnPrueba" value="Probando JQuery" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question about: What's the error? What are you trying? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The error says that the name 'actiondata' don't exist in my actual context, I´m trying to do a login but with jquery, without code behind

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static Credencial SetSession(string nick, string password)
{
   // do stuff...
}
```

script:

```
<script>
var objJson = {};
objJson.nick = 'xxx';
objJson.password = 'xxx';

$.ajax({
url: "wsSesion.asmx/SetSession",
            data: JSON.stringify(objJson),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
                //  success: function (msg) { alert(msg.d); },
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d.Identificador > 0) {
                    alert("TU Nick: " + msg.d.Nick + ", TU Identificador:  " + msg.d.Identificador);
                   window.location.href = "Acceso.aspx";
                }
                else {
                    alert("Usuarios y/o password incorectos");
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("ERROR" + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
            }
});
</script>
```

Comment: thats fine, but i want to do this with Data base values, including a stored procedure